# Uncaught PodioBadRequestError: "Must specify either 'embed' or 'url'"

Tags: podio

I need to set value for an embed field in Podio, and this is my code:

```
            $field_id='pdf-property-information';
            $options=$item->fields[$field_id]->values;
            if(empty($options)) 
                $item->fields[$field_id] =  new PodioEmbedItemField($field_id);

            // Create embed
            $embed = PodioEmbed::create(array('url' => $pdf_property_information));

            // Set using object
            $item->fields[$field_id]->values = $embed;

            // Set using associative array
            $item->fields[$field_id]->values = array('embed_id' => $embed->embed_id);
```

And this is the error I get:

> Fatal error: Uncaught PodioBadRequestError: "Must specify either
>   'embed' or 'url'" Request URL: http://api.podio.com/item/826141668
>   Stack Trace: #0
>   /home/apibind/public_html/mail_chimp/podio-php-4.3.0/lib/Podio.php(355):
>   Podio::request('PUT', '/item/826141668', Array) #1
>   /home/apibind/public_html/mail_chimp/podio-php-4.3.0/models/PodioItem.php(183):
>   Podio::put('/item/826141668', Array) #2
>   /home/apibind/public_html/mail_chimp/podio-php-4.3.0/models/PodioItem.php(66):
>   PodioItem::update(826141668, Array, Array) #3
>   /home/apibind/public_html/sourcingplatform/trunk/add.php(403):
>   PodioItem->save() #4 {main} thrown in /podio-php-4.3.0/lib/Podio.php
>   on line 289

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to pass the embed_id with array key `"embed"`. Here your final line will be like,

```
 // Set using associative array
 $item->fields[$field_id]->values = array('embed' => $embed->embed_id);
```